# Why when you close a program and then reopen it is it faster than just opening for the first time?

Tags: process, load

Suppose you open excel right after you turn on your computer, it is going to load at some speed. When you close it and then right after open it again, it will open faster. Why is that? This could be generalized to any process, why this happens? Thanks!